# Displaying multiple grids in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm trying to display 8 small grids in a page. Each grid has 2 columns and
 4 rows, with about 2 words per cell.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>
                hello world
            </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
```

I am opened to other suggestions on how to arrange them in a pleasing style, but what I was thinking was:

- if there is enough space to fit 4 in one line, display them on 2 lines: 4+4
- else if there is enough space to fit 3 in one line, display them on 3 lines: 3+3+2
- else if there is enough space to fit 2 in one line, display them on 4 lines: 2+2+2+2
- else display them on 8 lines

I don't really know how to do that, what would be the correct approach for this setup and conditionals ?

I can't even manage to display 2 grids on one line, it seems that by default a grid takes all the page width available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FlexLayout module to listen to media changes and set the number of columns based on the screen size. Then you bind the `cols` value to the number of columns variable. [Here is a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfjeow?embed=1&file=app/grid-list-flexible-example.ts).

HTML:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="columns" rowHeight="2:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>hello world</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * @title Flexible grid-list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'grid-list-flexible-example',
  styleUrls: ['grid-list-flexible-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'grid-list-flexible-example.html',
})
export class GridListFlexibleExample implements OnDestroy {
  watcher: Subscription;
  columns: number = 4;

  constructor(media: ObservableMedia) {
    this.watcher = media.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      if (change) {
        if (change.mqAlias == 'xs') {
          this.columns = 2;
        } else if (change.mqAlias == 'sm') {
          this.columns = 3;
        } else {
          this.columns = 4;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.watcher.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```