# angular material bootstrap like grid mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am trying to achieve Bootstrap style responsive screen using angular 2 and angular material.

Consider this example : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/
when we resize the window the thumbnails start stacking.

I am using angular material using mat-grid-list and I want to achieve the same behavior.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/oalnrrygvga?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.html

Material documentation regarding responsive layout grid define:

> The number of columns displayed in the grid is determined by the
>   breakpoint range (a range of predetermined screen sizes) at which a
>   screen is viewed, whether it’s a breakpoint for mobile, tablet, or
>   another size

1) So what needs to be done to achieve the same result in angular material as that of bootstrap

I found a solutions : 
[Responsive Design using md-grid-list in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891840/responsive-design-using-md-grid-list-in-angular-2/44846224#44846224)

Here they are using either non angular material library or using window size event. If material is supposed to be responsive we shouldn't be needing to do that.

So can some one please help me out how to get it done in purely material way .

Please see: I am beginner in front end design so I don't know lot jargons from UI world.

Thanks

Comment: Use [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) instead of the mat-grid.  If you want to use mat-grid and make it responsive, you will need to recalculate the number of cols depending on the screen size.

Comment: why is the question down voted without the giving the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular Flex-Layout provides this functionality in an "Angular" way. See [Displaying multiple grids in angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764401/displaying-multiple-grids-in-angular-material/50766875#50766875) for details.

Comment: As mentioned. Angular Flex-layout is a far better solution. 
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts